# DIV not aligned as expected on Firefox 3.5 (Mac)

Tags: css, macos, firefox, html

URL: http://www.ikebarberlearningcentre.ubc.ca/

The "For student" ,"For community", "For faculty", "For librarian" DIVs are expected to aligned as a 2x2 table.

It works on IE6+, Safari, Chrome and Firefox on PC. But on Firefox 3.5 on Mac, the "For Librarians" DIV is not aligned corrected. It is still on the left side, but it is blow the bottom boundary of "For Faculty" DIV (in other words, there is a large blank area between For Librarians and For Students DIVs).

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to accept answers to 11 of the other 12 questions you asked?

Comment: If it does fix problems, sure.

Comment: That's understandable. But if it not a hard question, I will not ask here. I do not ask questions without at least an hour's work that turned to no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself, simply by making each DIV a little bit more wide, and set the same min-height (>= the height of the longer cell in each row).

I don't think it is a perfect fix. I doubt the real back-end issue is how FF renders DIV on Mac. Maybe the defaulting rending (Static) is not about right. Probably "absolute" or "relative"? I don't know.